# Creating an adjacency list class in Python

Tags: python, adjacency-list

I was wondering how to create an adjacency list class

Here is what I have so far:

```
class AdjNode:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.vertex = value
        self.next = None

class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        

    # Add edges
    def add_edge(self, u, v):
        node = AdjNode(v)
        node.next = self.graph[u]
        self.graph[u] = node
```

Comment: Do you need anything fancier than the node label to represent a node? Regardless, the built-in `list` type is sufficient for storing lists of adjacencies in your `Graph` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very verbose example; not exactly what you want, but I feel it's a start, and as mentioned in the comments, uses a standard list.

I think you should look into classes further and attempt to understand OOP; I think you'd be doing yourself an injustice by not understanding what is being asked but rather asking what is being asked. - JUST MY OPINION

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = {}

    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        if u in self.graph:
            self.graph[u].append(v)
        else:
            self.graph[u] = [v]

    def deleteEdge(self, u, v):
        if u in self.graph:
            if v in self.graph[u]:
                self.graph[u].remove(v)
            else:
                print("Edge doesn't exist")
        else:
            print("Edge doesn't exist")

    def getNeighbors(self, u):
        return self.graph[u]

    def isAdjacent(self, u, v):
        if u in self.graph:
            if v in self.graph[u]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def printGraph(self):
        print(self.graph)
        
g = Graph()
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 3)
g.addEdge(2, 3)
g.addEdge(2, 4)
g.addEdge(3, 4)
g.addEdge(3, 5)
g.addEdge(4, 5)
g.addEdge(5, 6)
g.addEdge(5, 7)
g.addEdge(6, 7)
g.printGraph()
print(g.getNeighbors(1))
print(g.isAdjacent(1, 2))
print(g.isAdjacent(1, 5))
print(g.isAdjacent(5, 6))
g.deleteEdge(1, 2)
g.deleteEdge(1, 5)
g.printGraph()
```

Output:

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4, 5], 4: [5], 5: [6, 7], 6: [7]}
[2, 3]
True
False
True
Edge doesn't exist
{1: [3], 2: [3, 4], 3: [4, 5], 4: [5], 5: [6, 7], 6: [7]}
```